# Strange Issue in SSIS with WITH RESULTS SET returning wrong number of columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

So I have a stored procedure in SQL Server. I've simplified its code (for this question) to just this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DimensionLookup as
BEGIN
select DimensionID, DimensionField from DimensionTable
inner join Reference on Reference.ID = DimensionTable.ReferenceID
END
```

In SSIS on SQL Server 2012, I have a Lookup component with the following source command:

```
EXECUTE dbo.DimensionLookup WITH RESULT SETS (
(DimensionID int,  DimensionField nvarchar(700) )
)
```

When I run this procedure in Preview mode in BIDS, it returns the two columns correctly. When I run the package in BIDS, it runs correctly.

But when I deploy it out to the SSIS catalog (the same server the database is on), point it to the same data sources, etc. - it fails with the message:

> *EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 2 column(s) for result  set number 1, but the statement sent
>   3 column(s) at run time.*

Steps Tried So Far:

**Adding a third column to the result set** - I get a different error, VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA - which makes sense, kind of proof there's no third column.

**SQL Profiler** - I see this:

```
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,NULL,N'EXECUTE dbo.DimensionLookup WITH RESULT SETS ((
DimensionID int,  DimensionField nvarchar(700)))',1
SET FMTONLY ON exec sp_execute 1 SET FMTONLY OFF
```

So it's trying to use FMTONLY to get the result set data ... needless to say, running SET FMTONLY ON and then running the command in SSMS myself yields .. just the two columns.

**SET NOTCOUNT ON** - Nothing changed.

So, two other interesting things:

1. I deployed it out to my local SQL 2012 install and it worked fine, same connections, etc. So it may be a server / database configuration. Not sure what if anything it is, I didn't install the dev server and my own install was pretty much click through vanilla.

   1. Perhaps the most interesting thing. If I remove the join from the procedure's statement so it just becomes

   select DimensionID, DimensionField from DimensionTable

It goes back to just sending 2 columns in the result set! So adding a join, without adding any additional output columns, ups the result set to 3 columns. Even if I add 6 more joins, just 3 columns. So one guess is its some sort of metadata column that only gets activated when there's a join.

Anyway, as you can imagine, it's driving me kind of mad. I have a workaround to load the data into a temp table and just return that, but why won't this work? What extra column is being sent back? Why only when I add a join?

Gah!

Comment: And before anyone I asks, the procedure is actually dynamic, hence why I need to use WITH RESULT SETS. But it doesn't work even in this static example.

Comment: Never seen that, hell wasn't even aware of the `WITH RESULT SET` classifier. You say when you deploy to the 2012 server, it blows chunks. Is that actually the deploy step failing or "once it's deployed and I try to run it, then it blows up?" Either way, what about setting delay validation to true, does that make any difference? How about your cache mode? Assume FULL? What if you change it to None, any difference?

Comment: 1) Deploy is fine, only trying to execute (or even validate) package fails.
2) This is all runtime issues, so no way to "delay" validation.
3) Haven't messed with the cache, I'll give it a shot for kicks, but obviously I can't afford performance-wise to turn a warehouse lookup into a no-cache.

Comment: Local and dev at the same patch level? `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS version`

Comment: Nope, different versions - that may be it. where would I go to see what the difference patches are between versions? So I can see whether it's worth it to go submit a critical patch request now or wait until whatever our normal server upgrade schedule is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So all credit to billinkc: The reason is because of a patch.

In Version 11.0.2100.60, SSIS Lookup SQL command metadata is gathered using the old *SET FMTONLY* method. Unfortunately, this doesn't work in 2012, as [the Books Online entry on SET FMTONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx) helpfully notes:

> Do not use this feature. This feature has been replaced by sp_describe_first_result_set.

Too bad they didn't follow their own advice!

This has been patched as of version 11.0.2218.0. Metadata is correctly gathered using the **sp_describe_first_result_set** system stored procedure.

Comment: You did all the work tracking it down. I just asked questions ;)

Comment: As a workaround, I ended up declaring a table variable and pushing the dynamic SQL into it and then just ending the procedure with select * from @tableVar. Works on both versions.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the specified WITH results set in SSIS identifies that there are more columns than being returned by the stored proc being called. Check your stored proc and ensure that you have the correct number of output columns as the WITH results set.